# IOS XMLParsing. How to Load different key for same object

Tags: ios, xml-parsing

I am working on RSSFeed project. i want to fetch data from five different url's XML.

1) http://rss.news.yahoo.com/rss/world - Yahoo.com

2) http://news.google.com/news?pz=1&ned=us&hl=en&topic=w&output=rss -  Google.com

3) http://rssfeeds.usatoday.com/UsatodaycomWorld-TopStories - USA Today

I am able to Fetch data like Title and Description or etc with

`Object for key @"Ttile"` and `Object for key "@PUBDATE"`

But in Terms of Image all RSS Feed using Different Key for image Like 
`Object for key @"image"` , `Object for key @"src"` , `Object for key @"Media:content"`

I am able to fetch few of the Image with `Objectforkey:@"media:content"`
but other link uses different Objectforkey like @"image" or @"Media:thumbline".

How can i fetch it this different key or how can i set it in single tableview?

I am Using [**MWFeedParser**](https://github.com/mwaterfall/MWFeedParser) for XML Parsing.

Here is my code from which i am able to fetch image with `objectforkey:@"Media:content"` but i can't understand how to set other keys for image.

```
    //MWFeeditem.h
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
@interface MWFeedItem : NSObject <NSCoding> {

NSString *identifier; // Item identifier
NSString *title; // Item title
NSString *link; // Item URL
NSDate *date; // Date the item was published
NSDate *updated; // Date the item was updated if available
NSString *summary; // Description of item
NSString *content; // More detailed content (if available)
NSString *author; // Item author
NSString *image; // image for the feed

// Enclosures: Holds 1 or more item enclosures (i.e. podcasts, mp3. pdf, etc)
//  - NSArray of NSDictionaries with the following keys:
//     url: where the enclosure is located (NSString)
//     length: how big it is in bytes (NSNumber)
//     type: what its type is, a standard MIME type  (NSString)
NSArray *enclosures;

}

@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *identifier;
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *title;
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *link;
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSDate *date;
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSDate *updated;
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *summary;
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *content;
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *author;
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSArray *enclosures;
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *image;
@end
```

// MWFeeditem.m

```
#pragma mark NSCoding

 - (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)decoder {
 if ((self = [super init])) {
    identifier = [decoder decodeObjectForKey:@"identifier"];
    title = [decoder decodeObjectForKey:@"title"];
    link = [decoder decodeObjectForKey:@"link"];
    date = [decoder decodeObjectForKey:@"date"];
    updated = [decoder decodeObjectForKey:@"updated"];
    summary = [decoder decodeObjectForKey:@"summary"];
    content = [decoder decodeObjectForKey:@"content"];
    author = [decoder decodeObjectForKey:@"author"];
    enclosures = [decoder decodeObjectForKey:@"enclosures"];
    image = [decoder decodeObjectForKey:@"media:content"];

       }
 return self;
}

- (void)encodeWithCoder:(NSCoder *)encoder {
if (identifier) [encoder encodeObject:identifier forKey:@"identifier"];
if (title) [encoder encodeObject:title forKey:@"title"];
if (link) [encoder encodeObject:link forKey:@"link"];
if (date) [encoder encodeObject:date forKey:@"date"];
if (updated) [encoder encodeObject:updated forKey:@"updated"];
if (summary) [encoder encodeObject:summary forKey:@"summary"];
if (content) [encoder encodeObject:content forKey:@"content"];
if (author) [encoder encodeObject:author forKey:@"author"];
if (enclosures) [encoder encodeObject:enclosures forKey:@"enclosures"];
if (image) [encoder encodeObject:image forKey:@"media:content"];

}

@end
```

// MWFwwsparser.m

```
   - (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didEndElement:(NSString *)elementName
namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName {
MWXMLLog(@"NSXMLParser: didEndElement: %@", qName);
@autoreleasepool {

    // Parse content as structure (Atom feeds with element type="xhtml")
    // - Use elementName not qualifiedName to ignore XML namespaces for XHTML entities
    if (parseStructureAsContent) {

        // Check for finishing parsing structure as content
        if (currentPath.length > pathOfElementWithXHTMLType.length) {

            // Close XHTML tag unless it is an empty element
            if (!ELEMENT_IS_EMPTY(elementName)) [currentText appendFormat:@"</%@>", elementName];

            // Adjust path & don't continue
            self.currentPath = [currentPath stringByDeletingLastPathComponent];

            // Return
            return;

        }

        // Finish
        parseStructureAsContent = NO;
        self.pathOfElementWithXHTMLType = nil;

        // Continue...

    }

    // Store data
    BOOL processed = NO;
    if (currentText) {

        // Remove newlines and whitespace from currentText
        NSString *processedText = [currentText stringByRemovingNewLinesAndWhitespace];

        // Process
        switch (feedType) {
            case FeedTypeRSS: {

                // Specifications
                // http://cyber.law.harvard.edu/rss/index.html
                // http://web.resource.org/rss/1.0/modules/dc/ Dublin core also seems to be used for RSS 2 as well

                // Item
                if (!processed) {
                    if ([currentPath isEqualToString:@"/rss/channel/item/title"]) { if (processedText.length > 0) item.title = processedText; processed = YES; }
                    else if ([currentPath isEqualToString:@"/rss/channel/item/link"]) { if (processedText.length > 0) item.link = processedText; processed = YES; }
                    else if ([currentPath isEqualToString:@"/rss/channel/item/author"]) { if (processedText.length > 0) item.author = processedText; processed = YES; }
                    else if ([currentPath isEqualToString:@"/rss/channel/item/dc:creator"]) { if (processedText.length > 0) item.author = processedText; processed = YES; }
                    else if ([currentPath isEqualToString:@"/rss/channel/item/guid"]) { if (processedText.length > 0) item.identifier = processedText; processed = YES; }
                    else if ([currentPath isEqualToString:@"/rss/channel/item/description"]) { if (processedText.length > 0) item.summary = processedText; processed = YES; }
                    else if ([currentPath isEqualToString:@"/rss/channel/item/content:encoded"]) { if (processedText.length > 0) item.content = processedText; processed = YES; }
                    else if ([currentPath isEqualToString:@"/rss/channel/item/pubDate"]) { if (processedText.length > 0) item.date = [NSDate dateFromInternetDateTimeString:processedText formatHint:DateFormatHintRFC822]; processed = YES; }
                    else if ([currentPath isEqualToString:@"/rss/channel/item/enclosure"]) { [self createEnclosureFromAttributes:currentElementAttributes andAddToItem:item]; processed = YES; }
                    else if ([currentPath isEqualToString:@"/rss/channel/item/dc:date"]) { if (processedText.length > 0) item.date = [NSDate dateFromInternetDateTimeString:processedText formatHint:DateFormatHintRFC3339]; processed = YES; }

           ***// Changes Done here for image //***
                    else if ([currentPath isEqualToString:@"/rss/channel/item/media:content"])
                    {
                        if ([self.currentElementAttributes objectForKey:@"url"])
                            item.image = self.currentElementAttributes[@"url"];
                                                    processed =    YES;      }



                }
```

and here is my UITableview Method where i have to set image in cell.

```
   - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

     static NSString *MainTableIdentifier = @"MainTableIdentifier";
     MainViewTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:MainTableIdentifier];

 if (cell == nil)
  {
    NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"MainViewTableViewCell" owner:self options:nil];
    cell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];
   }


MWFeedItem *item = [itemsToDisplay objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
if (item) {

    // Process
    NSString *itemTitle = item.title ? [item.title stringByConvertingHTMLToPlainText] : @"[No Title]";
    NSString *itemSummary = item.summary ? [item.summary stringByConvertingHTMLToPlainText] : @"[No Summary]";


    cell.lblTitle.text = itemTitle;
    NSMutableString *subtitle = [NSMutableString string];
    if (item.date) [subtitle appendFormat:@"%@ ", [formatter stringFromDate:item.date]];
    //[subtitle appendString:itemSummary];
    cell.lblDateTime.text = subtitle;
    cell.lblDescription.text=itemSummary;


}
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:item.image];

   [cell.ImgMainView sd_setImageWithURL:url];
```

For More Reference Here i have Attached Pastie.org link with full code.

MWFeed parsers's class file with changes

**[MWFeedItem.h](http://pastie.org/10372147)**

**[MWFeedItem.m](http://pastie.org/10372152)**

**[MWFeedParser.h](http://pastie.org/10372154)**

**[MWFeedParser.m](http://pastie.org/10372158)**

Application's class file .

**[MainViewController.h](http://pastie.org/10372166)**

**[MainViewController.m](http://pastie.org/10372167)**

Comment: So is the feed parser actually helping you, or should you use something more generic like RestKit?

Comment: No i have used only feedparser for xml parsing.

Comment: So i'd suggest you look at a more generic solution which offers specific support for taking 'general' feeds and manipulating them into common model objects.

Comment: Is it not possible to do it in this feedparser ?

Comment: I guess you could have a specific configuration for each different feed source, or a wrapper configured with different extract keys for each source.  I have no direct MWFeedParser knowledge though...

Answer (score 0):

You could use different keys for different feeds or you could use different wrappers

Benefit of using different wrappers is keep one feed less dependent to other so that if any other keys are likely to change in the future you could handle easily and also can maintain readability of the code

You can also use enum data type like below

Declare enumerartors of type ParserSource in  MWFeedParser.h above the '@interface' line

```
typedef enum {
        YAHOO_FEED=0,
        GOOGLE_FEED,
        US_DAILY_FEED
    }ParserSource;
```

and declare a property to MWFeedParser class of type ParserSource like below

```
@property(nonatomic,assign)ParserSource feedType;
```

Then in you viewcontroller you know from which source the feeder is received and you can set the feedType of MWFeedParser there and modify your code for collecting data in -parser: didEndElement in MWFeedParser.m like below

```
if (!processed) {
if(self.feedType==YAHOO_FEED)
{
if (!processed) {
                if ([currentPath isEqualToString:@"/rss/channel/item/title"]) { if (processedText.length > 0) item.title = processedText; processed = YES; }
                else if ([currentPath isEqualToString:@"/rss/channel/item/link"]) { if (processedText.length > 0) item.link = processedText; processed = YES; }
                else if ([currentPath isEqualToString:@"/rss/channel/item/author"]) { if (processedText.length > 0) item.author = processedText; processed = YES; }
                else if ([currentPath isEqualToString:@"/rss/channel/item/dc:creator"]) { if (processedText.length > 0) item.author = processedText; processed = YES; }
                else if ([currentPath isEqualToString:@"/rss/channel/item/guid"]) { if (processedText.length > 0) item.identifier = processedText; processed = YES; }
                else if ([currentPath isEqualToString:@"/rss/channel/item/description"]) { if (processedText.length > 0) item.summary = processedText; processed = YES; }
                else if ([currentPath isEqualToString:@"/rss/channel/item/content:encoded"]) { if (processedText.length > 0) item.content = processedText; processed = YES; }
                else if ([currentPath isEqualToString:@"/rss/channel/item/pubDate"]) { if (processedText.length > 0) item.date = [NSDate dateFromInternetDateTimeString:processedText formatHint:DateFormatHintRFC822]; processed = YES; }
                else if ([currentPath isEqualToString:@"/rss/channel/item/enclosure"]) { [self createEnclosureFromAttributes:currentElementAttributes andAddToItem:item]; processed = YES; }
                else if ([currentPath isEqualToString:@"/rss/channel/item/dc:date"]) { if (processedText.length > 0) item.date = [NSDate dateFromInternetDateTimeString:processedText formatHint:DateFormatHintRFC3339]; processed = YES; }
}
else if(self.feedType==GOOGLE_FEED)
{

  ///////// different key name for image
}
else if(self.feedType==US_DAILY_FEED)
{
 ///////// different key name for image
}
```

change -(void)CallForWebService:(NSURL *)url as below

-(void)CallForWebService:(NSURL *)url fromSource:(ParserSource)sourceType
{

```
 //  NSURL *feedURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://techcrunch.com/feed/"];
feedParser = [[MWFeedParser alloc] initWithFeedURL:url];
feedParser.feedType=sourceType;
feedParser.delegate = self;
feedParser.feedParseType = ParseTypeFull; // Parse feed info and all items
feedParser.connectionType = ConnectionTypeAsynchronously;
[feedParser parse];
```

}

I Had a look at your MainViewController.m you depend on 11 online source for the Feed so you have to create enum with 11 types for the shortness of the answer I only mentioned three types

Comment: thanks for the replay . can you explain bit more ? i can't understand.

Comment: what is parser source ? thanks for replay and how can i set key in feeditem.m ? pleaase check once.

Comment: @BadalShah ParserSource is an enum data type, and you don't have to change any or declare any keys in feeditem.m , I have edited my answer

Comment: thanks for updated answer and i need to set `Parsersource` in place of `schedulemodetype` right ? and how it will be check key for image ?

Comment: oops its my mistake I change it to ParserSource . You can check like below 'self.feedType==GOOGLE_FEED' and get image form different sources

Comment: where i have to set key for google and yahoo ? like googla using `objectforkey:@"image"` and yahoo uses `objectforkry:@"media:content"`?

Comment: You can set them in the elementDidEnd delegate method of the parser as I posted in the answer